# unable to use Angular 6 for reading JSON data on meteo website REST api

Tags: json, angular, angular6

I'm trying to read JSON datas from this URL : https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/lat=46.259lng=5.235

My browser show me a JSON structure and the header contain Access-Control-Allow-Origin  *

Unfortunately, there are too much versions of Angular (I'm using v6) and too many differents examples (some only run under 4, some are AngularJS but the title still Angular, etc.)

Could someone give me a simple example with writing the JSON datas on the component view ? thanks.

here is what I'm trying without result for now :

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-get-data-info',
  templateUrl: './get-data-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./get-data-info.component.css']
})
export class GetDataInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  site = 'https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/';
  url  = 'lat=46.259lng=5.235';
  request = this.site + this.url;
  name: String = `Angular version ${VERSION.full}`;
  data: any;
  constructor(private myHttp: HttpClient) {
    this.data = this.test();
    console.log('END : le site a été lu par Angular ►' + this.request + 'et renvoit ' + this.data);
  }
  test() {
    console.log('test ► On m\'a appelé ?');
    return this.myHttp.get(this.request).subscribe((res: Response) => {
      this.data = res.json();
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: please apply a better code formatting

Comment: Don't search for random examples. Just read the official documentation of the framework you're using: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @MassimoCosta StackOverflow ask to use 4 spaces to use preformatted text. any better tips ? thanks by advance :)

Comment: you must leave a blank line before pre-formatted text. I edited your post to fix it . As @JBNizet said, start from official documentation and then try to find example on Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `this.data = this.test();` with just `this.test();`and modify `test()` to be

```
test() {
  console.log('test ► On m\'a appelé ?');
  this.myHttp.get(this.request).subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks ! I could read raw data, now I'll try to extract some values: many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` by default returns JSON data so

```
test() {
  console.log('test ► On m\'a appelé ?');
  this.myHttp.get(this.request).subscribe((res) => {
    this.data = res;
  });
}
```

should be good